# Deploying NGINX ingress controller using kubectl for docker desktop throwing error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops

I am trying to spin up an INGRESS NGINX controller using the below command.

**kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.7.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml**

But after executing, I am getting the below error

**kubectl : Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [2405:200:1607:2820:41::36]:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
after a period of time, or established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond.
At line:1 char:1**

- kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unable to conne...led to respond.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError**
  ```

Any suggestions to fix highly appreciated.

Comment: This error will occur when the **kubectl** is not able to communicate with the **cluster**. Are you able to execute any **kubectl** commands like `kubectl get pods`? Check this [link](https://techoverflow.net/2019/04/01/how-to-fix-kubectl-unable-to-connect-to-the-server-dial-tcp-443-i-o-timeout/) for troubleshooting.

Comment: @DharaniDharGolladasari Yes, I can execute all other Kubectl commands, but I feel Kubectl cannot access "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress" in order to retrieve the YAML file. Seems like users in India cant access "https://raw.githubusercontent.com" without using VPN.

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with ingress-nginx but rather the raw github content url seems to be an issue. The GitHub content domain has been blocked in some countries.
There isn't a proper solution to this but rather a workaround.
You could either :

1. Set your DNS to

> `8.8.4.4 and/or 8.8.8.8.`

These are managed by Google, and they are useful to bypass broken DNS from bad ISPs.

2. If you are in Linux environment then open your terminal window and copy/paste the below command:

> ```
> sudo -- sh -c "echo 185.199.108.133 raw.githubusercontent.com >> /etc/hosts"
> ```

For detailed explanation of this, you can look into this issue on github
[Not able to open https://raw.githubusercontent.com #42655](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/42655)